# Continuous functors

Tags: category-theory

Consider the category $\mathfrak{Top}$ of all small topological spaces. Let $C$ be any category and let $F:\mathfrak{Top}\longrightarrow C$ be any functor between them. Can a subcategory $D$ of $\mathfrak{Top}$ be constructed so that the restriction of $F$ on $D$ is continuous (or co-continuous)?

Comment: Sure, take $\mathcal{D} = \emptyset$. Then the condition is vacuous.

Comment: Is there a general way to study the continuity of a functor like the one defined?

Comment: Your question is too broad.